# Can't find SummaryReporter output

Tags: r, testthat

I've looked everywhere but I can't find where SummaryReporter writes the tests report?  If there's a single failure the script stops with an error.  Ideally, all tests would be run and results outputted to a file.

Comment: I presume you are talking about the `devtools` package?

Comment: I'm talking about the testthat package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very good documentation about the `testthat` package at this wiki:  https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Testing

In a nutshell, you can embed multiple `expect_that` statements in each `test_that`.

Towards the end of the page, in the section 'Testing files and directories' there is information about the three different reporters (stop, minimal and summary).

I have found this to be quite robust.  Even if test_that finds an error, it simply reports the error and carries on with the remainder of the tests.

PS.  My experience is that the test results are printed to the console.  I run my testing from within the R environment, not the OS command line.

Comment: That link is now a redirection to http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html but there is no documentation about reporters on that page. I have searched around and found no documentation about what reporters are or how to use/create them anywhere.

Comment: @zerweck As far as I know this was never sufficiently documented.

Answer (score 1):

SFun28, This may happen as your reporter is set to stop reporter as default.

Take a look at **hadley**'s [R paper on testing](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Wickham.pdf) (see page 8):

> testthat comes with three reporters: stop,
>   minimal and summary. The stop reporter is the default
>   and stop()s whenever a failure is encountered;
>   the summary report is the default for test_file and
>   test_dir.

Try specifying another reporter, so add this to your test_file call.

```
test_file("tests/test-mycode.R", reporter = "minimal")
```

or

```
test_file("tests/test-mycode.R", reporter = "tap")
```